# Can't find one bug in Wordpress translation .po file

Tags: wordpress, translation, launchpad

We are translating Wordpess to our language in Launchpad. Yesterday one of translators made unknown mistake and now generated .mo file shows all numbers greater than 1000 in such format: 1r264(instead of 1,264). For example 1,264 posts => 1r264 yazı, 4,874 comments - 4r874 serh...  It is so in all parts of Dashboard. I can not find where the mistake is? Any idea?
P.S. There is not any string for translation comma(,) such as ","=>"r", else it were very easy to solve.

Comment: Tomas, it is not wrong place and it is not directly related with translation process, the problem is related to number formats. So if you don't get the meaning of question, just ignore it please, dont put comments.

Comment: Then I really recommend improving your question, because it sounds like you made a typo in a translation and now Wordpress is acting up. Do you have a programming-related question?

Comment: Mr Tom, i repeat, you don't have to understand all questions asked in stackoverflow :) If Wordpress is not in your job area, then you can not get what i asked, just switch to another question. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

WordPress formats numbers with the `number_format_i18n` function (found in [wp-includes/functions.php](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3/wp-includes/functions.php#L144)).  That in turn uses `$wp_locale->number_format['thousands_sep']`, which is initialized in the [WP_Locale](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3/wp-includes/locale.php#L178) class.

That uses the `number_format_thousands_sep` string from the .po file.

Are you setting that?

Comment: Thank you Hobo, i found it after your answer. I checked wp-includes/functions.php, investigated that function you named.Then i found that one of translators translated the name of variable number_format_thousands_sep :) Of course variable names should not be translated.